# Sort book list collection by name ascending order as they inserted into the array??? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Hi I'm new at C++ and I'm trying to lean how to sort a book list by name in ascending order as they are inserted into the array.

Here is part of my code, just the insertion part.

```
void insertion()
{
    if (tail < MAX)
    {
        cout << "\nWhat is the name of the book?\n";
        cin.ignore(); 
        cin.getline(BookCollection[tail].title, 1023); 

        cout << "\nWhat is the price?\n";
        cin >> BookCollection[tail].price;
        cin.ignore(); 

        BookCollection[tail].id = tail;

        tail++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nERROR: Your collection is full. Cannot add new entries.\n";
        cin.ignore(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use something like a `std::set` if you want automatic ordering.

Comment: How do you think that should be done? Can you describe in natural language what the operations for the insertion would be?

Comment: The code shown is just populating an array `BookCollection`. If you want to sort on insertion then learn working of insertion sort.